# Deserialise JSON to polymorphic types based on a type field

Tags: scala, lift-json

I am using lift-json 2.6 and Scala 2.11.

I want to deserialise a JSON string representing a Map of 'sensors' to case classes (I don't care about serialisation back to JSON at all):

```
case class TemperatureSensor(
    name: String, sensorType: String, state: TemperatureState)

case class TemperatureState(
    on: Boolean, temperature: Float)

case class LightSensor(
    name: String, sensorType: String, state: LightState)

case class LightState(
    on: Boolean, daylight: Boolean)
```

What I have here are some common fields in each sensor class, with a type-dependant `state` field, discriminated by the `sensorType` property

The idea is I invoke a web service and get a map of sensor information back, this can be any number of any type of different sensors. I know the set of possible types in advance, but I do not know in advance which particular sensors will be returned.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "1":
    {
      name: "Temp1",
      sensorType: "Temperature",
      state:
        {
          on: true,
          temperature: 19.4
        }
    },
  "2":
    {
      name: "Day",
      sensorType: "Daylight",
      state:
        {
           on: true,
           daylight: false
        }
    }
}
```

(The real data has many more fields, the above case classes and JSON is a cut-down version.)

To consume the JSON I start with:

```
val map = parse(jsonString).extract[Map[String,Sensor]]
```

This works when I omit the `state` fields of course.

How can the extraction process be told which type of `state` to choose at run-time, based on the value of the `sensorType` field? Or do I have to write a custom deserialiser?

This question relates specifically to lift-json, not any other JSON library.

Comment: https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-non-supported-types

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have not used lift-json... But I recently tackled the same problem using play-json. Perhaps some of what I have done could be useful to you as well.

See my github page for code: [DiscriminatedCombinators.scala](https://github.com/srushingiv/org.skrushingiv/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/skrushingiv/json/DiscriminatedCombinators.scala)